# Getting synthetic methods from an ITypeBinding

Tags: java, generics, eclipse-jdt, synthetic

I'm playing with the `ITypeBinding` that I get when calling `resolveBinding()` on an `ASTNode` in the AST made by `ASTParser` and a K_COMPILATION_UNIT from a Java Project.

For example I have resolved an ITypeBinding for `java.lang.String`, but the synthetic methods are missing (`compareTo(Object)` in this case). The documentation for ITypeBinding states that the synthetic methods may or may not be there, but the isSynthetic method suggests there should be some way of convincing the ITypeBinding to include synthetic methods as well.

If I get an `IType` by calling `ITypeBinding.getJavaElement()` it contains the synthetic methods I'm looking for, but it would be easier if I could get them from the ITypeBinding directly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found my answer by looking at the implementation which explicitly skips synthetic methods - first by skipping them when recovering methods from the compiler AST and then by always returning false from the implementation of isSynthetic method - this is so for Eclipse 3.7.